# Overriding Styles in Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I am working to customize this theme: http://themeforest.net/item/ultimate-directory-responsive-wordpress-theme/8043893

Per the protocol I have used on many site, I have created a child theme.

In this child theme I have a style.css file with the following code:

```
@import url("../ultimate-directory/ud-assets/css/custom.css");
@import url("../ultimate-directory/style.css");

#header {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 3px solid;
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

I also have a functions.php file in the child theme with this code `

```
<?php
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
  function enqueue_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
  } 
?>
```

but the style.css in the child theme is not overriding the parent styles. I have gone back and forth with the theme developers but they have not provided a solution. The parent theme has a style.css but nothing is in it, just a comment that says all the styles are in the css folder which is within the ud-assets folder. The style sheet I'm trying to override is called custom.css which is why I imported it but my changes are still ignored.

This is the code within the parent theme header.php which calls in the styles I believe:

```
$cp_preloader_status = get_option(THEME_NAME_S.'_enable_preloader'); 

if( $cp_preloader_status == 'enable' ){
?>
<?php $preloader = get_option(THEME_NAME_S.'_preloader_gif','1'); ?>
<style>
/* Loader */
.loader { background: url("<?php echo CP_THEME_PATH_URL; ?>/ud-assets/img/preloaders/<?php echo $preloader; ?>.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% rgb(249, 249, 249);height: 100%;left: 0;position: fixed;top: 0;width: 100%;z-index: 99999;}

<?php if ( is_page( '563' ) || is_page( '1018' ) || is_page( '1021' ) || is_page( '966' ) || is_page( '812' ) || is_page( '825' ) || is_page( '827' ) || is_page( '961' ) ){ ?>
#main {
margin: 0 !important;   
}
<?php } ?>
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is the file actually present in your <head>?

Comment: How is the parent CSS enqueued?

Comment: Is the childs function.php ever called?

Comment: I have tried adding a direct link to the child style.css in the header.php within the child theme but that didn't work.

Comment: The code above for the function.php is within the child theme so not sure what you mean by "called"

Comment: There are multiple css files in the parent theme. The parent style.css is empty but it says all the files are in the stylesheet folder which has 19 stylesheets. The css I'm trying to override is in the ud-assets/css/custom.css -- I have tried mirroring file structure in my child theme and placing my desired code in my custom.css but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The code above does not load any css files it does provide a couple of css rules though.

You have a couple of options to actually over-ride the parent files which may be loaded later than the file you are trying to enqueue and hence the later rules will apply (dependant on specific css rules and use of `!important` etc).

1. Add your action to load later (really you should check the page source to determine if this is the issue)

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme', 1000 );
   ```
2. Use specific protocols for css selectors if you are making minor changes
   e.g. `nav ul li.custom` will select li's in a nav element with the class custom. Dont use `nav ul li` if you want to style nested uls later.
3. Dequeue all styles and enqueue again (probably best practice not to load more than 1 css file anyway

   ```
   function dequeue_css(){

    global $wp_styles;

           foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $name ) :
                   wp_deregister_style ($name);
                   wp_dequeue_style ($name);           
           endforeach; 

           // now enqueue css files
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_css',100);
   ```